# Can I ever stop using Tora

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

I just completed chapter 1 of Xenoblade Chronicles 2. I really like the idea of this game (I never played the first one). One thing that absolutely makes me want to throw my controller at my T.V. screen is the voice-overs for Tora. I can't stand that character at all. From the broken english to the "MEH MEH MEH" every 15 seconds while I'm in a fight.

Does the game get to a point where I can replace Tora with another party member? Up until now, my party has been fixed. Does it ever get to a point where you have choice over your Drivers, similar to how you have choice over your party in some Final Fantasy games after a while?

I understand that there may be parts through the entire game where Tora is involved (hopefully there's some short-lived scene where he/she/it dies) - but I just need to know... am I going to have to live with this annoying character for the entirety of the game? I'm not sure I can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can!

Consider trying the japanese voice over with subtitles and/or adjusting the audio options to your likings otherwise in terms of volume. You can bench Tora in a later chapter as there will be a new driver that can fufill a tank role.

However there is a point in the game where the game subtly recommend you use Tora, but I found I didn't need to as I enjoyed being slightly overleveled just from playing the game and using rest experience at inns (this also helps as trash mobs many levels below you won't bother aggroing you).

I'll admit I've played most of the game (currently at chapter 8) with Tora benched as I don't want/enjoy grinding Tiger Tiger.

Edit: In discussion posts I've read elsewhere it is recommended that you use Tora as your tank for post end game content like superbosses. I had no trouble beating the main story with Tora benched though.